# Google App Engine - Change package for a persistent class

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, google-cloud-datastore

My GWT app is deployed on Google App Engine for Java. I have persisted instances of a class in the app engine datastore. Now I want to move that class to a different package, but it leads to problems in deserializing the existing objects.

So, is there a way I can move the class to a new package? I don't mind updating the existing objects if that helps me achieve my goal.

Thanks.

Comment: What 'problem' do you get deserializing? Stacktrace please!

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would move my.package.Clazz to my.**new**.package.Clazz. The basic idea is to do the migration via a third "temporary" class (TempClazz in this case):

- create new class my.package.TempClazz (do NOT simply rename Clazz)
- create a helper method that will read all existing Clazz entities from the datastore, then copy the data into the new TempClazz instance and store the TempClazz entities in the datastore.
- now deploy to GAE and run the helper method to copy your Clazz entities to TempClazz entities.
- if that worked. Delete Clazz-entities.
- next, basically repeat the process, except that this time you actually refactor my.package.Clazz into the new package my.**new**.package.Clazz. So at this point you will have two classes: my.package.TempClazz and my.**new**.package.Clazz.
- all that's left to do is again to read TempClazz from the datastore and copy each into a Clazz-entity.

Pretty involved. Maybe someone knows an easier way?

Comment: Why not just duplicate the definition in the new package, and copy entities directly from the old one to the new one?

Comment: @Nick, have you tried that? If your suggestion works, I do not understand why the OP has trouble deserializing existing entities using the new class in the first place. The docs state that the entity-key is derived from the simple name of the class and thus I assumed that trying to persist/retrieve different entities with the same class name is a bag of hurt. Cf. http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/dataclasses.html#Class_and_Field_Annotations

Comment: I'm doing some more investigation into this and will get back with the results. I'm seeing that in some cases I've a problem in deserialization and in others I don't. For example, I have a persistent ClassA, which has a persistent field of type ClassB, which further has a persistent field of type ClassC. If I move Class C from com.dfb.client.ClassC -> com.dfb.shared.ClassC, I get a deserialization error saying "com.dfb.client.ClassC" not found (or something similar). Let me do thorough analysis and report the exact findings. Thanks for your help.